# Azure DevOps Work Item reason is not updating when State is update through automation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

While updating state of work item **Reason** is not updating automatically in Azure DevOps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making a state change from Azure DevOps UI, It will be considered as a transition and the respective reason will be updated. Reasons are written based on the state transition in Azure DevOps work item type definitions.

Through automation, if you do any state update or change from one state to another, it won't be considered as a transition. So you need to update the Reason field along with the state value.